# ...として言うけど not meaning 'however' -- how can we include that meaning?

Tags: grammar

> 男として言うけど、彼女は大切にしろ。

This translates to something like

> I say this as a man, cherish your girlfriend.

Is this けど just emphatic? If it is, how can I say "I am saying this as a man, but you should cherish your girlfriend". I guess it's ambiguous in English too, but the meaning of this sentence is more "I may not know (as I am a man), but you should value your girlfriend.

Another example would be something like "I say this as an alcoholic, but you should stop drinking". This *but* in English creates quite a big difference in the meaning of the sentence:

> **A:** "I say this as an alcoholic, but you should stop drinking" = "This may be hypocritical advice,  but ..."

> **B:** "I say this as an alcoholic, you should stop drinking" = "This advice is very accurate as I am experienced, ..."

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate. The questioner is familiar with the use of けど・が introducing the topic of conversation, and interested in how you would make it clear you want to male a contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> 男として言うのが**どうかと思う**けど、彼女は大切にしろ。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
> 男として言うのも**どうかと思う**けど、彼女は大切にしろ。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
> 男として**言うのがなんだけど**、彼女は大切にしろ。
> 男として**言うのもなんだけど**、彼女は大切にしろ。

どうかと思う is a common phrase used to express the speaker's disagreement of the said subject implicating it is not necessarily the best/most correct.

言うのもなんだけど is another set of common phrase that has the strong nuance of "...Might not be in best position to say but.."

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](https://hermes-ir.lib.hit-u.ac.jp/hermes/ir/re/14360/ryugaku0001000110.pdf) about けど usage, the closest should be 注釈(note).

It can be reverse as

> 彼女は大切にしろ、男として言うけど.

So the けど is indicating 男として as an additional information on from what perspective the speaker is making a statement rather than making a logical connection between the two phrases.